# Nodejs GraphQL cannot connect to interface on localhost

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am setting up a GraphQL API for accessing postgreSQL database on localhost but currently I can not connect to the GraphQL browser interface. I have checked that node is up to date and graphql dependecies are installed, the client configurations are correct as I can access the database through psql.

After I run `node server.js` in the root directory and access the api through its url in a browser it loads forever and nothing happens. The code is working on my partner's machine so I am not sure what is going on.

How can I log any errors after app.listen?

```
const express = require('express')
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql')
const graphql = require('graphql')
const { Client } = require('pg')
const joinMonster = require('join-monster')

const client = new Client({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    database: "postgres"
})
client.connect() 

......


const app = express()
app.use('/api', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
}))

app.listen(4000, () => {
 console.log('Server running on port %d', 4000);
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine for graphql connection but I think the problem in connection with pgSQL so uses seqlize ORM for pgSQL.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Answer (score 0):

```
//server.js

import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import cors from 'cors';
import config from './server/config/environment';
import schema from './server/data/schema';

if (config.env === 'production') {
  // Launch GraphQL
  const graphql = express();

  graphql.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));


  graphql.use('/graphql', graphQLHTTP((req, res) => ({
      schema,
      graphiql: true
  }))
  );

  graphql.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(chalk.green(`GraphQL is listening on port ${config.port}`))
  });
}

//db.js



 import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
    import {Op} from 'sequelize';
    
    
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('', '', '', {
      host: 'localhost',
      port:5432,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      operatorsAliases: Op,
    })
    
    // model list
    const models = {
        Admin: sequelize.import('./admin'),
      };
    
    models.sequelize = sequelize;
    module.exports = {
        models
    }

// schema.js

var {
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLBoolean,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull
} = require('graphql');

var Db = require('./db');

var Sectors = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'sectors',
  description: 'list of all the sectors',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        resolve (sectors) {
          return sectors.id;
        }
      },
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve (sectors) {
          return sectors.name;
        }
      }
    };
  }
});

var Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'Root query object',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      sectors: {
        type: new GraphQLList(Sectors),
        args: {
          id: {
            type: GraphQLInt
          },
          name: {
            type: GraphQLString
          }
        },
        resolve (root, args) {
          return Db.models.sectors.findAll({ where: args });
        }
      }
    };
  }
});

var Schema = new GraphQLSchema({query: Query});
exports.default = Schema;
```